# Присваивание переменной каждой строке и отправка post запроса

Tags: python

Есть файл list.txt в нем:

```
47362758
33958295
20959483
92905983
```

Из этого файла надо присваивать переменную параметру в post запросе с первой строки до последней c тайм-аутом 3 сек.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'id': '2908fh3h83495jf',
}

data = 'Json={"AddAccount":[{"To_Account":"Тут переменная из строки"}],"From_Account":"98385473"}'

response = requests.post('https://example.com/add', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: А может ты сам попытаешься это написать прежде чем клянчить у других? И вот если у тебя не получится вот тогда ты выложишь сюда свой код, в котором ты хотя-бы пытался это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а что мешает сделать так:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        data = f'Json={{"AddAccount":[{{"To_Account":"{line}"}}],"From_Account":"98385473"}}'
```

или вам что-то другое нужно было?

Comment: f' строки и скобки {}

Comment: SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply

Comment: `f'Json={{"AddAccount":[{{"To_Account":"{line}"}}],"From_Account":"98385473"}}'` В f-строках фигурные скобки как символ нужно писать по два раза

Comment: да, чуть ошибся

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in open('list.txt','r'):
    payload = {"AddAccount":[{"To_Account":i.strip()}],"From_Account":"98385473"}
    data = "Json="+json.dumps(payload)
    ....
```

Comment: Можете показать как применить этот код с моим примером? буду очень признателен!

Comment: просто вставьте в середину))

Comment: С вашим примером и @Zhihar у меня получилось сделать один post запрос. Можете подсказать как можно сделать цикл для всех строк из файла?

Comment: пост положи внутри цикла